# Add play button to toolbar

Tags: javascript, html

I have recently seen a play button in the tab menu which triggers an action in that page. (When opening a youtube video in a new tab)

Here is a picture of it:

[image: Play button in Firefox Nightly toolbar]

Does anyone know how to add such a button?

(Picture made in Firefox Developer Edition - 57.0b13)

Comment: It's not a button. It's a favicon, or you're talking about the audio playing indicator that some browsers have added.

Comment: I guess OP's talking about the play button next to the close icon in the right tab, not the favicon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a browser feature, you can't "add" it, but it will automatically be displayed when you have an `audio` or `video` element on your site that is playing sound, giving users the possibility to mute and unmute sound for the specific tab.

Comment: I have meant the play button and not the disable sound button, but I guess it's the same for both.
Tested it out now: Firefox will show the play button when a new tab with an autoplay video is opened. Chrome doesn't seem to have it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to implement the icon by yourself. Chrome or any other modern browser automatically displays that icon when that specific tab makes a sound.

But if you want to implement a button by yourself, 
You would want to alter the 'title' of the page with a Unicode icon when you start playing a sound. Not very practical method though.

Comment: I was aware of the automatic sound icon, I meant the play button (seems to be the same principe though, see answer by connum+comment). And by altering the title I can't add a clickable button, right?

Comment: Oh no I don't think that you can add a clickable button there. Although the idea seems pretty interesting. Developers could add buttons for various operations like **next song** or **pause song** for youtube